# how do I skip the error in kdb when running a function?

Tags: kdb

```
func:raze {select compTypeOrigin from .get.order[2021.10.01;string x]}

list:(``abc`def`ggh``eef)
```

when I ran this function it works

```
raze {select compTypeOrigin from .get.order[2021.10.01;string x]} `abc
```

but I got the type error when its empty(`), probably due to the function .get.order

I tried to run the function with protected evaluation

```
@[func;each list[0 + til 6];show]
```

but it doesnt work
How can I skip the error ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to bring the each (`'`) outside the protected evaluation. Try this syntax:

```
q)f:{x*x}
q)list:(1;`a;3)
q)@'[f;list;{x}]
1
"type"
9
```

Comment: beat me to it....

Answer (score 2):

`func` is currently not a function, but a mixed list. `raze` should be placed inside the function to make it a function.

Error traps only trap errors during execution of the function. In your case the error is being thrown beforehand, during the setup of the parameters during `each list[0 + til 6]`. The reason this is throwing an error is because `each` expects two parameters (an operator and the parameters) and only one is being supplied.

```
/ func is currently not a function, but a mixed list
q)type func
0h
/ put the raze inside the lambda
func:{raze select compTypeOrigin from .get.order[2021.10.01;string x]}
/ type now 100h (lambda)
q)type func
100h
/ move the each outside
@[func;;show] each list[0 + til 6]
```